# Getting System.InvalidOperationException exception with breeze and WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am very new to breeze. I have downloaded the template for AngularBreeze and trying to create a sample application but i am stuck on Breeze WebApi Controller.

```
BreezeController]
public class ProductsBreezeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ProductRepository context;

    public ProductsBreezeController()
    {
        context = new ProductRepository();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return context.Metadata();
    }

    //// GET api/productsbreeze
    public IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return context.TodoLists;
    }
}

public class ProductRepository : EFContextProvider<SampleEntities>
{
    public DbQuery<Product> TodoLists
    {
        get { return Context.Products; }
    }
}
```

**Exception Message**

Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.String Metadata() on type AngularWebApi.ApiControllers.ProductsBreezeController System.Linq.IQueryable`1[AngularWebApi.DataAccess.Model.Product] GetAllProducts() on type AngularWebApi.ApiControllers.ProductsBreezeController

**ExceptionType**: "System.InvalidOperationException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your breezewebapiconfig.cs up to accept an action parameter as we'll.  currently you have a controller only probably.

Open appstart folder and BreezeWebApiConfig.cs and add it there (should see something like ) -

```
Breeze/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

And you need to add the action part in there

**Edit**

In your question it clearly shows the route for that controller action is api/productsbreeze.  If that is the route you are hitting then you need to adjust that route to accept an action as well.  If it is the Breeze route you are trying to hit then add an HttpGet controller attribute on the action

```
//// GET api/productsbreeze
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    return context.TodoLists;
}
```

You need to make sure that your BreezeWebApiConfig is also registered in the Global.asax, of course.

Comment: i added that but still the same error `public static class BreezeWebApiConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBreezePreStart()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("BreezeApi", "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
                );
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("BreezeDefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );
        }
    }`

Comment: so what should be there ?

Comment: {action} should be after controller.. On the API route as well

Comment: is that what you are talking about `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("BreezeApi", "breeze/{controller}/{action}/{id} ", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );`

Comment: I slightly adjusted my answer.  I am not sure exactly what the URL you are hitting is but you need to make sure that it is decorated properly and also that your configurations accept and process action paramters

Comment: i was doing something wrong which is corrected and now its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Requesting URL should be matched with Breeze Api Configuration.

**Server Side Configuration**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("BreezeApi", "breeze/{controller}/{action}");
```

**Client Side**

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("/breeze/ProductsBreeze");
```